# wp_nav_menu returns menu list in ascending order. How can I arrange the menu same as dashboard menu

Tags: php, menus, html5

```
 <?php
              wp_nav_menu(array(
                  'theme_location' => 'primary',
                  'container' => 'ul',
                  'menu_class'=> 'top-menu'
                  /* 'walker' => new Walker_nav_Primary() */
                  )
              );                  
          ?>
```

This is a simple wp_nav_menu

[image]

You can see ascending order from above example

I have done this in WP.

[image]

wp_nav_menu gives me ascending order menu. How can I arrange as dashboard?

Please help.

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you double check you have a theme location called 'primary'. This could depend on the theme being used. It would be set using "register_nav_menus" possibly in the theme's functions.php file. If there is no location called 'primary' you would just need to set it to the correct name.

Comment: yes, you can see below primary menu has right sign

Comment: Is the menu actually in this reverse order if you inspect the page's HTML ? `wp_nav_menu()` is supposed to output the menu in the same order as it is set in the back-end as you would expect ; so I suspect the order is only reversed with CSS on your front-end.

Comment: no its not dude. not in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use below code  in your theme funcation.php file

```
function my_asc_nav_menu($menu, $args) {
if (isset($args->reverse) && $args->reverse) {
return array_reverse($menu);
}
return $menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_asc_nav_menu', 10, 2);
```

> And also use your wp_nav_menu function as below:

```
 wp_nav_menu(array(
              'theme_location' => 'primary',
              'container' => 'ul',
              'menu_class'=> 'top-menu',
              'reverse' => FALSE,

              )
          );
```

Comment: i don't want to this like reverse or with sorting i need as same as dashboard order.

Comment: Ok then please double check have you install any plugin or implemented the hook related to the menu because WordPress default functionality is that menu display same order as dashboard

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, if the theme_location is incorrect, the menu defaults to alphabetical order, rather than the order set on your menu screen.

I can see you have a tick next to Primary Menu in the menu settings, but the actual key / slug might be different in your theme. For example:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'customkey' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
    'social'  => __( 'Social Links Menu', 'twentysixteen' ),
) );
```

If you do a search for:

```
register_nav_menus
```

in the code of your theme, you should be able to find the correct value.

You can then add this to your code, for example:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
              'theme_location' => 'customkey',
```